Vertical positioning of subscripts in math mode depending on superscripts is unexpected
I was trying to align subscripts in factors of a term like X_y^zX_y, and the first thing I tried was X_y^zX_y^{\mathstrut}, but this did not work. So I investigated and discovered some quite unexpected behavior:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$X_y^z X_y
X_y^{\vphantom{z}} X_y^{}
X_y^{\mathstrut} X_y^{\vphantom{(}} X_y^{(}$

$X_Y^z X_Y
X_Y^{\vphantom{z}} X_Y^{}
X_Y^{\mathstrut} X_Y^{\vphantom{(}} X_Y^{(}$
\end{document}


So, just adding ^{} seems to always lower the subscript, but adding ^{\mathstrut} lowers only some subscripts. As \mathstrut is supposed to be defined as \vphantom{(}, I tried with ^{(}, and this also does not always lower the subscript, even when plain ^{} does.
How can this behavior be explained or predicted?

You do not show what you get, but, with some tracing in ConTeXt (that uses the Opentype math and not the traditional that you might use, but it will be essentially the same arguments, perhaps with different names).
Look at the picture below.

The gray lines are, from top to bottom, the line where primes align, the line where superscripts align, the line where subscripts align, the line where subscript aligns in case there are also superscripts.
The second examples show that we get the baseline of y and Y sitting on the third line.
The first examples (your order) shows that the z sit on the second line, while the y and Y sit on the fourth one.
The third and fourth examples show that the y and Y can sit on the bottom one if one fake a superscript.
The fifth to seventh examples show that the Y might be pushed down if needed, if what sits in the superscript has too much depth. This would also happen to the y if that was taller. And it would also happen to the y if the object in the superscript had a larger depth.
I don't say that this is exactly what you see, but I guess it is essentially the same principle for (traditional) LaTeX.
The input I used was
\showglyphs

\starttext
$\mathscriptbelow X_y^z X_y
X_y^{\vphantom{z}} X_y^{}
X_y^{\mathstrut} X_y^{\vphantom{(}} X_y^{(}$

$\mathscriptbelow X_Y^z X_Y
X_Y^{\vphantom{z}} X_Y^{}
X_Y^{\mathstrut} X_Y^{\vphantom{(}} X_Y^{(}$
\stoptext


I've added pdflatex output.
